# Nodejs with express stop responding request after some time working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-session

I have my server running but after some time working it stops responding requests, keep trying to load the page give me couldn't establish connection.

My app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var oracledb = require('oracledb');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var multer = require('multer');
var fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
var sessionStore;
var app = express();

var oracleDbStore = require('express-oracle-session')(session);

var connect = require(path.join(__dirname, 'connection', 'conn'))(2);

oracledb.createPool(connect, function(err, pool) {
      if (err) {
        console.error("createPool() error: " + err.message);
        return;
            }
            pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
                if (err) {
                    handleError(response, "getConnection() error", err);
                    return;
                }
                var diffopt = {externalAuth: true,
                            checkExpirationInterval: 900000,
                            expiration: 86400000,
                            createDatabaseTable: true,
                            connectionLimit: 1,
                            schema: {
                                tableName: 'sessions',
                                columnNames: {
                                    session_id: 'session_id',
                                    expires: 'expires',
                                    data: 'data'
                                }
                            }};
                var options = Object.assign({},connect,diffopt);
                sessionStore = new oracleDbStore(options, connection);
            });
        });

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'twig');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(fileUpload());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use('/files',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/archivos',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'archivos')));
app.set('trust proxy', 1);
app.use(session({
    secret: "work",
    name: 'sessionId',
    store:sessionStore,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));

var links = require('./links');

for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++){
    app.use(links[i].route, require(links[i].direction));
}

app.get('*',function(req,res){
    res.redirect('/');
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views/index.twig'));
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Log of a server when stop responding but still get requests. It can't load any of views or static files.

```
GET /files/stylesheets/jquery-ui.css - - ms - -
GET /files/jscript/jquery.min.js - - ms - -
GET /files/stylesheets/font-awesome.min.css - - ms - -
GET /files/stylesheets/style.css - - ms - -
GET /files/stylesheets/AdminLTE.css - - ms - -
GET /files/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css - - ms - -
GET / 304 2.676 ms - -
GET /files/stylesheets/AdminLTE.css - - ms - -
GET /files/stylesheets/style.css - - ms - -
GET /files/stylesheets/font-awesome.min.css - - ms - -
GET /files/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css - - ms - -
GET /files/stylesheets/jquery-ui.css - - ms - -
GET / 304 2.759 ms - -
GET /files/stylesheets/jquery-ui.css - - ms - -
GET /files/jscript/jquery.min.js - - ms - -
GET /files/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css - - ms - -
GET /files/stylesheets/font-awesome.min.css - - ms - -
GET /files/stylesheets/AdminLTE.css - - ms - -
GET /files/stylesheets/style.css - - ms - -
GET /login 200 1.157 ms - 1417
GET /files/imagenes/up.jpeg - - ms - -
GET /files/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css - - ms - -
GET /files/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css - - ms - -
POST /login - - ms - -
```

In the end i need to restart the server to make it work again.

Comment: My suspicion, since you can't establish a connection at all, is that the process is terminating. Unless you're running out of resources, this is probably due to an unhandled exception. My suggestion would be to play with it, figure out how to make it break at will, and then beef up the error logging around the point of failure so you can debug it.

Comment: same suggestion, play with it by using try catch and figure our where the server is exiting.

Comment: I would guess that you are not releasing some sort of database resource and eventually you run out of resources.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for responding, the problem was oracledb pool, when it expires it hangs the server. I changed it for express-file-store and now its working ok.

```
app.use(session({
    store: new FileStore(options),
    secret: "work",
    name: 'sessionId',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));
```

Comment: You probably had a session pool larger than the number of threads available to node-oracledb.  See Connections and Number of Threads [https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/v1.12.2/doc/api.md#numberofthreads] in the doc.  It points out that each connection will block a thread.  You should bump UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE before starting Node.  The node-oracledb session pool has some advantages over external pools, particularly around load balancing and dead connection detection.